# issue with value from bean not displaying correctly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spinner

i have a template page which has all the code i need for ten pages, where the only diff between the pages is some values

the majority of these have been working fine, however i have an issue with this section of code :

```
            <p>
                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{tooltipBean.sectionSave}" 
                           stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
                           disabled = "#{formBean.number != 1}" >  
                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue " process="@this" />  
                </p:spinner> 

            </p>
```

the idea behind this code is it goes to the tooltipBean get the section save value, add this value into here and then for this to get the value from another bean

the value in the tooltipBean is

```
 sectionSave = "#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}";
```

and i use the template in the view pages by:

```
 <f:event listener="#{tooltipBean.setupForPageA}" type="preRenderView" />    

            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/commonForm.xhtml"/>
```

i have it working normally without using the template by using :

```
        <p>
            <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                       stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
                       disabled = "#{formBean.number != 1}" >  
                <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue " process="@this" />  
            </p:spinner> 

        </p>
```

that code would give me the value 71 in the spinner, however the code from the template displays in the spinner #{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne} which is correct i just need this to run and return 71 rather than showing me the value of the code

does this make sense, sorry if i have written it confusingly i am unsure on how to describe the issue

i think it just not getting intalised at the right time, would it be possible to intatlise the page with the values first and then give it time for that new value to get the data in this case 71 before being viewed by the user

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify EL from a backing bean like that.  The spinner control assumes that it will have both get and set access to whatever is passed in as its value attribute.  It won't try to interpret the specified value as EL, which could be quite a dangerous side affect.

Here's how I would approach it.  Pass in the value as a parameter to your template:

```
<ui:include src="templates/commonForm.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="spinnerValue" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" />
</ui:include>
```

Then, reference that parameter in your template:

```
<p>
    <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{spinnerValue}"
               stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
               disabled = "#{formBean.number != 1}" >  
        <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue " process="@this" />  
    </p:spinner> 
</p>
```